# Docker: MeteorJS gets installed twice with some warnings

Tags: ubuntu, docker, meteor, dockerfile

I am using a `ubuntu:latest` image to create a meteorJS docker image.
The problem is, that meteor is downloaded twice and I do get some warnings for package.json.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# build arguments
ARG APP_PACKAGES
ARG APP_LOCALE=en_US
ARG APP_CHARSET=UTF-8
ARG APP_USER=app
ARG APP_USER_DIR=/home/${APP_USER}

# set the locale (required by Meteor)
RUN locale-gen ${APP_LOCALE}
RUN localedef ${APP_LOCALE}.${APP_CHARSET} -i ${APP_LOCALE} -f ${APP_CHARSET}

# create a non-root user that can write to /usr/local (required by Meteor)
RUN useradd -mUd ${APP_USER_DIR} ${APP_USER}
RUN chown -Rh ${APP_USER} /usr/local
USER ${APP_USER}

# MeteorJS
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

# NPM packages
WORKDIR '/builds/project/data'
RUN meteor npm install gridfs-stream gm fluent-ffmpeg
```

And the last part (`RUN meteor ...`) gives me this:

```
This is your first time using Meteor!
Installing a Meteor distribution in your home directory.
Downloading Meteor distribution
```

So meteor is downloaded twice:

1. curl ...
2. meteor npm install ...

Also I do get this warning:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/builds/project/data/package.json'
npm WARN media No description
npm WARN media No repository field.
npm WARN media No README data
npm WARN media No license field.
```

Why should there be a package.json, although I do not use `--save`?

Comment: I don't see you installing curl and curl command is not there by default in ubuntu. So how come `RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` is this working?

Comment: You are right. I skipped this part from the Dockerfile to keep it readable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are changing user in between the Dockerfile which is causing permission issues. Below dockerfile works great for me

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl
# build arguments
ARG APP_PACKAGES
ARG APP_LOCALE=en_US
ARG APP_CHARSET=UTF-8
ARG APP_USER=app
ARG APP_USER_DIR=/home/${APP_USER}

# set the locale (required by Meteor)
#RUN locale-gen ${APP_LOCALE}
#RUN localedef ${APP_LOCALE}.${APP_CHARSET} -i ${APP_LOCALE} -f ${APP_CHARSET}

# create a non-root user that can write to /usr/local (required by Meteor)
RUN useradd -mUd ${APP_USER_DIR} ${APP_USER}
RUN chown -Rh ${APP_USER} /usr/local
USER ${APP_USER}

# MeteorJS
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

# NPM packages
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/builds/project/data
WORKDIR '/usr/local/builds/project/data'
RUN meteor npm install gridfs-stream gm fluent-ffmpeg
```

The two key changes I made are below

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/builds/project/data
WORKDIR '/usr/local/builds/project/data'
```

You want to create the directory your self, instead of letting `WORKDIR` create it. The directory you create will have permissions that belongs to your user. But if the directory doesn't exist then you use `WORKDIR` and it creates the directory then it won't have correct permission.

Next because you switched user you no longer have permission to create `/builds/project/data` in root. But you do own `/usr/local/` so you should that as the starting path. Also the npm warning that you see is ok, it will always warn if `package.json` is not there and you are trying to install local module. So you can ignore it as long it say `WARN`

Comment: Understand. But I need to use the given workdir, as my CI will pull the data into this directory. So I do get permission problems right now...

Comment: Then change `RUN chown -Rh ${APP_USER} /usr/local` to `RUN mkdir -p /builds/project/data && chown -Rh ${APP_USER} /usr/local /builds/project/data` and change `WORKDIR` back to `WORKDIR /builds/project/data`